# SQL SERVER OBJECT_ID

Tags: sql-server

i want to execute the query in master database it self

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'DB1.dbo.T_table1', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'db1.dbo.T_table1'), 
                       'KEY_value','AllowsNull') IS NOT NULL 
SELECT 'TRUE' AS COLUMNSTATUS 
ELSE 
SELECT 'FALSE' AS COLUMNSTATUS
```

but its not working? give me suggestion.

Comment: is it giving you an error? if so: what error? is it just not returning the data expected? What did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: When testing from master database, i get the false value

But i am executing in DB1 i got true value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing from master, i get the NULL as expected from

COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'db1.dbo.T_table1'),'KEY_value','AllowsNull'),

But when running this on the database to be tested, it returns the 1/0 as expected.

It seems that COLUMNPROPERTY runs on the db being executed.

EDIT:

Try this from master

```
DECLARE @RetVal TABLE(
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO @RetVal (Val) EXECUTE ('USE DB1; SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N''DB1.dbo.T_table1''),''Key_Value'',''AllowsNull'')')

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @RetVal
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for NULL, but COLUMPROPERTY will return 1 or 0, if the field exists.

Try:

```
SELECT CASE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'db1.dbo.T_table1'),
           'KEY_value','AllowsNull') 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Column exists and does not allow nulls'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Column exists and allows nulls'
        ELSE 'Column not found'
    END
```